# An array of polynomials can be considered as a tensor?

Tags: vectors, tensors, tensor-rank

if $\{1, x, x^2, x^3, \dots, x^{n-1}\}$ is the base of a vector space, can I say that is $\bar{P} = [ P_1, P_2, \dots, P_m]$ a tensor? Where each $P_i$  is a combination of the monomial base. If it's, What is its dimension?

I'd like to thank in advance.

Comment: do you know the concept of tensor? what makes you think that a set of polynomials is a tensor?

Comment: @janmarqz, answering your first question, I'm beginning in this subject. Anyway, I'm saying that like a vector where each components has a base and it's represented as an array, but we know that it is not an array. Can I've the same thought ? because ever position in the array has  a combination of bases from a vector spaces. This idea brings me hesitation, but at the same time I think that  a function $F$($\Omega \subset R^n \rightarrow R$) can be invariant to a 
bijective coordinate transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you bound the degree of polynomials in an array by, say $d$, and since
$$P_i=P_i(x)=a_{i0}+a_{i1}x+...+a_{id}x^d,$$ 
where the $a_{ij}$ are taken from a field, say $\mathbb R$, then the vector space of your $\tilde P$ objects, collected into a set, let's called $V$, 
will have $\dim V=(d+1)^m$.

For, if we denote by $\mathbb R_d[x]$ the abelian group of polynomials of degree $d$ at most, then 
$$V=\mathbb R_d[x]\times\cdots\times \mathbb R_d[x],$$
is the cartesian product of $m$ factors, with each factor having
$\{1,x,x^2,...,x^d\}$ as basis.

Elements of a vector space are also dubbed **rank one contravariant tensors**.